# Wordpress not detecting curl

Tags: curl

I have wordpress installed on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
My Curl version is curl 7.58.0

when I enable the WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway I get error message.
"WooCommerce Gateway PayPal Checkout requires cURL to be installed on your server".

Any help on how I can get woocommerce to detect curl?

Comment: Maybe you need the curl PHP extension (package `php-curl`).

Comment: I tried :   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-gd php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-dev php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-mbstring php7.2-intl php7.2-zip php7.2-bcmath   but it didn't work

Comment: @TomMust I am experiencing the same exact problem. I have the same versions!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you installed curl but not php-curl. Use apt to install it:

```
sudo apt install php-curl
```

Then restart apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

...and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried that but i'm still getting the "WooCommerce Gateway PayPal Checkout requires cURL to be installed on your server"  message

Comment: Which version of PHP does the site use? Could it be that you installed php-curl for a different PHP version?As a test, can you run PHP in REPL mode (command line mode) from a terminal (php -a).  Also check php version from command line: php -v.

Comment: I'm running: PHP 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @EricMintz Same here!

Answer (score -2):

Install the version specific php curl package.

If you are running PHP version: 7.3, install `php7.3-curl`.

`apt install php7.3-curl`

Comment: The package [`php7.3-curl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=php7.3-curl&searchon=names) is currently _not_ available for any supported Ubuntu release by default repositories.

Comment: But [this search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=php+curl&searchon=names) is quite helpful for working out which versions are available